# Blinking effect missing

Tags: office-2013

About one year ago I developed an app that, among other things, had to select parts of word documents and let them blink... just one line like this

`Selection.Range.Font.Animation = MSWord.WdAnimation.wdAnimationBlinkingBackground;`

The app worked pretty: if you open those docm documents (they have some macro inside) you can see some part blinking...
Now my customer tried it on a brand new laptop using Office 2013 and, surprise, when you open same word documents blinking effect is missing.

Is there a known reason for this?
Is there a way I can solve it?

Comment: According to [this article](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/features-of-office-2013-word-that-changed-compared-to-office-2010-word/), "Text Animation is missing in Office 2013 Word."

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelLiu - while that doesn't answer the "why" or come from Microsoft, at least we know we're not alone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdanimation%28v=office.15%29.aspx), the `WdAnimation` enumeration has been deprecated:

```
This object, member, or enumeration is deprecated and is not intended 
to be used in your code.
```

I can't find any other reference as to why it was dropped, or suggested replacement.

As a workaround, I just changed the background color. Non-blinking.

Comment: I see you opened a bounty on this question: should I wait to mark your answer as the correct one? Thanks for your post!

Comment: Er.... maybe? I was hoping to find _anything_ talking about this online. Not one wispy blog post did I find mentioning it. I'm just setting the background color for now (storing the original, and restoring it when done with the highlight need). Still, deprecation without docs is annoying.

Comment: Consider I had an app changing docs info with blinking... completely wasted... imagine my surprise :(

Comment: Doesn't look like we're bringing anybody out of the woodwork; might as well assign it to me. :::sigh:::